# pygame isn't working on visual studio code (I'm using mac os catalina)

Tags: python, pygame

please can anyone help me to sort out this issue. when i try to import pygame it's not working and giving me this error

#
import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame

i'm using python 3.8 and os catalina

Thanks.

Comment: Pygame is not a standard module - you need to have it installed somewhere. What does your directory structure look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your import statement is `# import pygame` then remove the # symbol

Open the terminal and run `pip install pygame` and then try to import pygame

If you are using any virtual environment first activate the virtual environment from the project location and then run the above command

Comment: thanks for the reply ! I have done this but still when I try to do it in visual studio code but still giving me the same error. AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init'